# Radius of convergence query

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Find the radius of convergence of the series of $\frac{2^n(4z-8)^n}{n}$

My answer: $(4z-8)^n=4^n(z-2)^n=2^{2n}(z-2)^n$. Let $c_{n}=\frac{2^{3n}}{n}$. Then $\frac{c_{n}}{c_{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{2n}$ so radius of convergence is 1/2. This disagrees with 'Pauls online notes, which says it is 1/8.

Comment: Why leave out the $2^n$ in front?  And even if we leave it out, your ratio should have a $4$, since $2^{2n}/2^{2n+2}=1/4$.

Comment: You introduce $c_n=\frac{2^{3n}}n$, then $\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{2n}$ instead of $\frac{n+1}{2^3n}$. Double check your derivations.

Answer (score 3):

By the root test we have

$$\left|2^n\frac{(4z-8)^n}n\right|^{1/n}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}2|4z-8|<1\iff|z-2|<\frac18\iff z\in B\left(2,\frac18\right)$$
so the radius is $\frac18$.

Answer (score 2):

Your ratio is incorrect. You should have:

$$\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}=\frac{2^{3n}(n+1)}{2^{3(n+1)}n}=\frac{2^{3n}(n+1)}{2^{3n+3}n}=\frac{n+1}{2^3n}$$

Comment: thank you, very stupid error